# How to pass single param to separate feature file

Tags: karate

I've tried below to send a param to separate feature file ( by following [this example](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/callfeature/call-feature.feature) ) but, it is not working as expected.

project.feature

```
   * def id = '55000000005021'
   * def result = call read('delete_project.feature')
```

delete_project.feature

```
 Given path 'project', '#(id)'
 When method DELETE
 Then status 200
 Then match response.status == 'success'
```

Getting below exception

> com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: projects.feature:48 - 
>   delete_project.feature:11 - status code was: 404, expected: 200,
>   response time: 239, url: https://localhost:8080/project/%23(id)
>   response:
>   {"status":"failure","data":{"error_code":"INVALID_URL_PATTERN","message":"Please
>   check if the URL trying to access is a correct one"}}     at ✽.* def
>   result = call read('delete_project.feature') (projects.feature:48)

One more doubt, How to iterate this by passing list of ids. I've multiple id in foo variable, I would like call **delete_project.feature** for each id availble in that foo variable.

```
* def foo = get response.data[*].id
```

Comment: created a separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55016948/hot-to-iterate-list-of-params-through-separate-feature-file , please do help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you over-complicated the path params, change to:

```
Given path 'project', id
```

And read this part of the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#rules-for-embedded-expressions