# How to iterate list of params through separate feature file?

Tags: karate

How to iterate this by passing a list of ids. I've multiple ids in foo variable, I would like call **delete_project.feature** for each id available in that foo variable.

project.feature

```
* def foo = get response.data[*].id
* def del = call read('delete_project.feature')
```

delete_project.feature

```
 Given path 'project', id
 When method DELETE
 Then status 200
 Then match response.status == 'success'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By passing list of id's as a input to your feature you can actually make the call iterate feature that many times.

```
* def foo = get response.data[*].id
* def createId = function(x) {return {"id" :x}} 
* def ids = karate.map(foo,createId) 
* def del = call read('delete_project.feature') ids
```

Refer [data driven feature](https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-features) in karate